# The WordPress editor breaks when I try to save a page with a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need help. I don’t understand what is happening. I created a shortcode. There he is

```
 function mainslider_function() {
    function lesson_slider() {

        $open_div = '<div class="autoplay">';
        $close_div = '</div>';

        if( have_rows('test_fields', 'option') ):
            echo $open_div;
            while ( have_rows('test_fields', 'option') ) : the_row();
                $sub_value = get_sub_field('image');
                echo '<div class="slide"><img src="'.$sub_value.'"></div>';
            endwhile;
            echo $close_div;
        endif;
    }
return lesson_slider();
}
```

And it works. But only to the front. When trying to edit a page with this shortcode. The WordPress editor stops working.  I understand that the problem is that I use a function in a function. Because when I test this code:

```
 function mainslider_function() {
    $test = 'test message';

    return $test;
}
```

Everything is working fine. And if I do like this

```
function mainslider_function() {
    function test(){
        $test = 'test message';
        echo test;
    }
    return test();
}
```

The editor stops working. Tell me, please why this is happening?

Comment: Probably because by doing that, calling `mainslider_function` more than once will raise a fatal error stating that your inner function is already defined. Don't know much about WP's good practices, but I'd say either define the inner function as a "global" one instead (properly named/namespaced) or test for its existence with `function_exists`.

Comment: Check please the errors in server.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the inner function. You could just concatenate your string or use output buffering.

Comment: @Jeto    Can you show me an example. I'm not so strong at php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an inner function. You could concatenate your string parts or use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php).

With the latter, this becomes:

```
function mainslider_function()
{
  ob_start();

  if (have_rows('test_fields', 'option')) {
    echo '<div class="autoplay">';
    while (have_rows('test_fields', 'option')) {
      the_row();
      $sub_value = get_sub_field('image');
      echo '<div class="slide"><img src="', $sub_value, '"></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }

  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Note: also did a bit of code cleanup in the process.

Comment: You are a magician, thank you very much you saved my day!!!!! Thanks a lot really. I will try to figure out line by line to improve my knowledge.

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if that worked for you (green tick on the left).